# Executing SQL query against DataBase for an unknown object in EntityFrameworks

Tags: entity-framework, objectcontext

Correct me if I am wrong about EntityFramewroks.

As far as I understand, it is impossible to execute a query against the database when you do not know what results (objects) you are going to get in return because it needs to map the results to the expected object, which is passed when executing raw SQL query against the database.

Question: How can one execute SQL query without specifying the object?

Your help (and any input) will be highly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Moses

Answer (score 0):

It is still unclear what you are asking, but I will adapt answer to your edits of your question.

I think you are referring to something like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj592907.aspx

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); 
}
```

or

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogNames = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>( 
                       "SELECT Name FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); 
}
```